# Query to transfer from ODBC

Tags: mysql, database, domo

I have a database connection using ODBC.. i want to write a query to transfer all tables and columns to export the data in DOMO..

select* from database ()

Can someone help in a query where i can replace only with the new data?

Comment: A single query will return a single table with many columns and all the data merged. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ODBC database connection has been made (using Domo workbench or cloud connector) and the data is present in Domo, you can add a transform (in MySql or Redshift - refer screenshot), in which you can write your query [select * from database].

Once you have finished writing your transform(s), you can 'Add Output Dataset' (see screenshot) to extract the data.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJXvL.png)